# Equivalent of Iterator.continually for an Iterable?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

I need to produce an `java.lang.Iterable[T]` where the supply of `T` is some long running operation. In addition, after `T` is supplied it is wrapped and further computation is made to prepare for the next iteration.

Initially I thought I could do this with `Iterator.continually`. However, calling `toIterable` on the result actually creates a `Stream[T]` - with the problem being that the head is eagerly evaluated, which I don't want.

How can I either:

1. Create an `Iterable[T]` from a supplying function or
2. Convert an `Iterator[T]` into an `Iterable[T]` without using `Stream`?

Comment: All other **Iterables** are eager not only in its head, but in all its elements... so I doubt any of them would work for you. Have you tried robust **Streaming** libraries like `fs2`, `Akka Streams`, `Monix Observables` or `zio.ZStreams`.

Comment: What is the interoperability with Scala and Java collections like? Ultimately I need to produce a `java.lang.Iterable[T]`

Comment: Well, talking about **fs2**, you can end up with something like `stream.compile.toList.unsafeRunSync().asJava` to produce the **Java iterable**, but that would evaluate all the Stream, meaning it is not longer lazy... I doubt you can really create a **Java Iterable** that is lazy.

Comment: Well - that's pretty easy, as `java.lang.Iterable` is a very simple interface and one can just return an Iterator. Which makes me think...

Comment: Why not just convert the **Scala Iterator** to a **Java** one then?

Comment: Silly me - I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13, you can use [`LazyList`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html):

```
LazyList.continually(1)
```

Unlike `Stream`, `LazyList` is also lazy in its head.

Comment: Arrgh it even has a `continually` method - what a tease. Sadly, I'm stuck on 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

Because `java.lang.Iterable` is a very simple API, it's trivial to go from a `scala.collection.Iterator` to it.

```
case class IterableFromIterator[T](override val iterator:java.util.Iterator[T]) extends java.lang.Iterable[T]
val iterable:java.lang.Iterable[T] = IterableFromIterator(Iterator.continually(...).asJava)
```

Note this contradicts the expectation that `iterable.iterator()` produces a fresh `Iterator` each time; instead, `iterable.iterator()` can only be called once.

Comment: Unlike a stream-based solution, this can unfortunately only be iterated over once, which could cause surprising bugs. Too bad Java doesn't have scala.collection.IterableOnce.